# Context popup menu in wix/react-native-navigation navbar

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, react-native-popup-menu

Is it possible to set three dot context menu using "react-native-popup-menu" in "react-native-navigation" navbar? 
or do we have any other approach to set three dot context menu in both IOS and Android with "react-native-navigation" navbar?

Comment: hm... it looks like there is no straight forward solution (that works for both ios and android) for RNN as it is meant to be really native navigation and therefore does not support so high level of extensibility with custom components.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can control the priority and positioning of each button (On Android) using the `showAsAction` property. See the [docs](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/adding-buttons-to-the-navigator) for more details.

In short, the following snippet will add two buttons to the menu and one outside:

```
static navigatorButtons = {
  rightButtons: [
    {
      id: 'btn1',
      title: 'Menu button 1'
      showAsAction: 'never'
    },
    {
      id: 'btn2',
      title: 'Menu button 2'
      showAsAction: 'never'
    },
    {
      id: 'btn3',
      title: 'Regular Button'
      icon: require('./img/button.jpeg'),
      showAsAction: 'always'
    }
  ]
);
```

This isn't available on iOS since on iOS an action sheet is usually used instead of a menu.

Answer (score 0):

I've been wondering about this as well, and found a solution:
Generally, all the Menu parts **have to** be inside of the `Menu` tag, so the `MenuTrigger` as well.
You can style the `MenuTrigger` but I didn't get it into the top bar with that.

Good news: It's even easier than that, simply place the whole `Menu` into your `navigationOptions` like this:

```
static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => ({
  title: 'Uploaded Videos',
  drawerLockMode: 'locked-closed',
  headerRight: 
    <Menu renderer={SlideInMenu} style={{ zIndex: 10 }}>
      <MenuTrigger text="open menu"/>
      <MenuOptions style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <Text>Menu</Text>
        <MenuOption onSelect={() => { console.log("clicked") text="Click me" />
      </MenuOptions>
    </Menu>
```

Caveat: `navigationOptions` are static, so in your menu you can't use functions of the component. But there are ways around that, see for one example [this issue at react-native-navigation](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/147). Generally, you should probably use redux for that.

Hopefully this still helps you!

Answer (score 0):

I actually made my own context menu with this library:
https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-modal

So basically it is a modal with its background completely transparent. The content of the modal is rendered just below the "three dot context menu" - button. 
By using their onBackdropPress function, you can dismiss the context menu if the user press outside the menu.